# EXCEL Deadline-tracker: Counting "distance" of empty cells (in a row) until you reach an event

Tags: date, excel-formula, counting, deadlines

I want to display the number of weeks it takes until an event is happening for a certain Item (B4, B5, etc.). My timeline is in weeks on the x-axis increasing to the right. There are empty cells in the row until i.e. "event 1" is reached.

[image: Example]

I want to display the weeks it takes until a that "event 1" is reached from today (in C4, C5 or D4, D5). It would be perfect if excel can refer **to the actual current date the file is opened**.

Either by counting the empty cells from the current week or by a formula that refers to the week it takes place and then counts backwards with the dates.

Does anyone have a straightforward solution. Would be really thankful!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing this, if i have understood correctly, then this should work accordingly as per the required request:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C4</kbd>

```
=LET(α, $F4:$BE4, IFERROR(COLUMNS(DROP(TAKE(α,,XMATCH(1,1/(α=C$3))),,
                  XMATCH(1,1/(WEEKNUM(+$F$3:$BE$3)=WEEKNUM(TODAY())))+1)),0))
```

---

- Using the first `XMATCH()` returns the position of `Event 1`
- Using `TAKE()` to extract the number columns required.
- Using the second `XMATCH()` with `WEEKNUM()` function to get the position of the present weeks number.
- Using `DROP()` to exclude the number columns not required.
- Lastly, using `COLUMNS()` function to get the counts.
- Now, fill down and fill right.

---

**Shorter & Quicker Version:** Using `TOROW()` & `TOCOL()` <sup>**MS365 Exclusive**</sup>

[image]

---

```
=TOROW(WEEKNUM(+F$3:BE$3)/(F4:BE4=TOCOL(C$3:D$3)),3)-(WEEKNUM(TODAY())+1)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Another solution - put the formula in C4:

```
=LET(event,C$3,
tasks,$E4:$U4,
weeks,$E$3:$U$3,
dateEvent,XLOOKUP(event,tasks,weeks,0,0),
IF(dateEvent > TODAY(),(dateEvent -TODAY()+WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2) - 1)/7,""))
```

You can drag it to the left and down to get the other results

[image]